# Is there a way to make the headers uniform throughout a document regardless of page breaks?

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there a way to make the headers uniform throughout a document regardless of page breaks?

I have a word document with multiple 'Next Page' breaks. I also have a header that I want to be formatted the same throughout the whole document.

However, somehow the headers between 'Next Page' breaks have changed so that some are right up against the page margins and others are not.

**It would be best if I could do this via a single step rather than going through each page break and adjusting the header margins**

Comment: It sounds like you are using "section breaks" rather than "page breaks". Section breaks allow the page format to change between sections whereas all a page break does is force the next paragraph to appear on a new page. http://www.howtogeek.com/73928/change-the-type-for-a-section-break-in-word-2007-and-2010/

Comment: Yes sorry: there are a mix of section and page breaks. Any means to quickly solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you can use the "Find & Replace" tool to replace section breaks with page breaks.

According to [Replace Section Breaks with Page Breaks Automatically?](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/replace-section-breaks-with-page-breaks-automatically.2734057/) you can search for a section break using `^b` to find a section break, and then in the "replace with" box put in `^m`.

Alternatively in the Find/Replace dialogue you can go to the "special" button at the bottom and select the section or page break item.

The excerpt from Herb Tyson's answer on that page:

> To discover these symbols (and others), in Find and Replace, click the More
>   button. At the bottom, drop down the Special list. Note that special
>   search/replace characters can vary for Find what: and Replace with:. They
>   can also vary if the Use wildcards option is selected. In this case, don't
>   enable Use wildcards, and put ^b in Find what: and ^m in Replace with.